# Adding a hide function to jquery dropdown script on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm currently using this following script to operate my dropdown menu so that when a user clicks the menu item the drop appears and they can currently click anywhere outside the screen to make the menu disappear but i was wondering how id go about adding functionality to make the dropdown disappear by clicking the menu item again (while keeping the option to click anywhere outside the item). Is this hard to implement?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* for keeping track of what's "open" */
    var activeClass = 'dropdown-active', showingDropdown, showingMenu, showingParent;
    /* hides the current menu */
    var hideMenu = function() {
        if(showingDropdown) {
            showingDropdown.removeClass(activeClass);
            showingMenu.hide();
        }
    };

    /* recurse through dropdown menus */
    $('.dropdown').each(function() {
        /* track elements: menu, parent */
        var dropdown = $(this);
        var menu = dropdown.next('div.dropdown-menu'), parent = dropdown.parent();
        /* function that shows THIS menu */
        var showMenu = function() {
            hideMenu();
            showingDropdown = dropdown.addClass('dropdown-active');
            showingMenu = menu.show();
            showingParent = parent;
        };
        /* function to show menu when clicked */
        dropdown.bind('click',function(e) {
            if(e) e.stopPropagation();
            if(e) e.preventDefault();
            showMenu();
        });
        /* function to show menu when someone tabs to the box */
        dropdown.bind('focus',function() {
            showMenu();
        });
    });

    /* hide when clicked outside */
    $(document.body).bind('click',function(e) {
        if(showingParent) {
            var parentElement = showingParent[0];
            if(!$.contains(parentElement,e.target) || !parentElement == e.target) {
                hideMenu();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my attempt based on the answer below:

```
/* function to show menu when clicked */
dropdown.bind('click',function(e) {
    if (!dropdown.data('open')) {
    dropdown.data'(open', true);
    // open menu
    } else {
    dropdown.data('open', false);
    // close menu
    }

});
```

Although im getting errors so i assume ive played it in incorrectly or perhaps overwritten something? This is just a section from the code above as it's the only section ive edited with this answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use jQuery.data() and have a variable called open for example which is true or false depending on the state. So you could be something like this.

```
if (!dropdown.data('open')) {
dropdown.data'(open', true);
// open menu
} else {
dropdown.data('open', false);
// close menu
}
```

Comment: Where abouts would i place this? Would it be part of the click funtion?

Comment: Yes, inside you click event handler / function. The first time it won't be delcared so it will open it and declare it as true, so that the second time you can close it and set it back to false.

Comment: I'm going to edit the question to include my attempt, could you just look over it, im sorry to be a pain my skills in jquery suck.